# Where are Facebook's settings for Notes?

Tags: facebook

I want to use the import function to import RSS, but that setting has vanished or do you know where it is? I use FB as a different user who has notes and it used to work.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use the import function to import RSS but that setting has vanished or do you know where it is?

Yeah, facebook has [discontinued the](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=206051139465982#My-blog-isn%27t-importing-to-Facebook.) notes import feature in favour of pages. Consequently, you'll no longer be able to import RSS as notes.

Comment: Not really in favor of pages as you can still create your own notes, you just can't import blogs into notes anymore.